# How to eliminate blank spaces when determining GPA/Grade Score on Excel Grade Template

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am looking to eliminate blank spaces counting as a "0" when determining grades on a transcript.  I can't figure out how to get the if statement to work.  I'm on a MacBook pro laptop.  Current formula in D11 is: =SUM(Grades[@[KPI 1]:[KPI 6            ]])/72

I have included a screenshot of the sheet.  It now looks as if everyone in the sample is failing as it won't calculate based on grades that are actually in there.  Ideally, the letter grade and scores would calculate just on the assignments that have been completed and not be accurate until the end.  I have included a screenshot of the spreadsheet. Any help on how to update the formula is appreciated!

[Grade Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYjhy.png)

Comment: Can you explain how the formula should work? Why divide by 72? Blank cells don't contribute anything to `SUM()`, . That is, there would be no difference between including empty cells and excluding them  like there might be in an average calculation.

Comment: I eliminated the 72 in my formula (I put it there b/c that was the total number of grades) and it does prevent it from adding in any blank cells, but there will be 72 deliverables eventually and I'm not sure how to make it continue to calculate the grade average.  Removing the 72 makes it just keep adding the percentages together instead of averaging the ones that have been entered.  Look like his got me closer, but not sure how to get the average of those sum of grades rather than just the sum as written.  I hope that helps clarify.

Comment: Okay, changed it to AVERAGE instead of sum, which made the first cell work, but I get this error in subsequent cells; any idea why? #DIV/0!

Comment: Actually, I see.  Duh! The cells were empty.  New to this, but this is what I needed.  How do I upvote your answer bugdrown?  That simple question made me realize my error!  Problem solved!

Comment: If you can't upvote my comment then no worries. I didn't actually create a formal answer.

Comment: One more note, you could also use `SUM()/COUNT()` across the same cell range. I think that's what you we working toward originally.